# Are Bastila Shan and Satele Shan related?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I noticed the same last name and I knew that Bastila had children so I was wondering if Satele was a descendent of Bastila.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes

[Bastila Shan's Wookieepedia page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bastila_Shan#Legacy) says:

> Revan and Bastila's family line eventually led to Satele Shan, the Grand Master of the Jedi Order during the post-Great Galactic War era

And [Statele Shan's Wookieepedia  page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Satele_Shan) says:

> The daughter of Jedi Knight Tasiele Shan, who was herself a descendant of the legendary Jedi Knights Revan and Bastila Shan, Satele was born on the planet Brentaal IV in the year 3699 BBY.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are related. She is a descendant of Bastila and Revan.